# how to fetch values in self.find after using :from in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
players_data =  self.find(:all,
  :order => 'name',
  :conditions => 'p.country = c.id and p.position = po.id',
  :select => 'p.id as id, p.name as name, c.country as country, po.position as position, p.rank as rank',
  :from => 'players as p, countries as c, positions as po'
)
```

## --------------------------------

players_data.each do |row|
      #puts " The Row === #{row.country}"
      tmpArray = []
      tmpArray[0] = row.id
      tmpArray[1] = row.name
      tmpArray[2] = row.country
      tmpArray[3] = row.position
      tmpArray[4] = row.rank

I'm unable to get the values for country and position.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing straight SQL logic with ActiveRecord logic and getting undesirable results.  Consider using Associations instead:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :position
end

players = Player.find(:all)
players.each do |player|
  puts player.country.name
  puts player.position.rank
end
```

If you want to use Rails conventions, define the foreign keys as table_id (i.e. a Player has a country_id and position_id column).  This allows for the Association magic to work.

If you are working with legacy database tables, you can further specify the associations following the [ActiveRecord Associations API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).